# Unable to click on the Login link at the right hand side of the page using Protractor

Tags: protractor

Below is the HTML code. Unable to click on the Login link at the navigation bar at the right hand side of the page .

```
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
<li class="online" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginPopup">
<a href="#">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in">
</span> Login
<div class="ripple-container">
</div>
</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try 
**element(by.css('.glyphicon.glyphicon-log-in').click();**